# Sum of all Residues at the poles of the function $f(z)=\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{(z+a)^2}$, where $a \in \mathbb{Z}-{0}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, singularity

> Sum of all Residues at the poles of the function $f(z)=\frac{\cot(\pi
>  z)}{(z+a)^2}$, where $a \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$
>
> (a)$\frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+a)^2}-\pi
> cosec^2 \pi a$
>
> (b)$-\frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+a)^2}-\pi
> cosec^2 \pi a$
>
> (c)$\frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+a)^2}+\pi cosec^2 \pi a$
>
> (d) $-\frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+a)^2}+\pi
> cosec^2 \pi a$

We want $$\sum_{a \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}} Res_{z=-a}\frac{\cot(\pi
 z)}{(z+a)^2}$$

$$Res_{z=a}\frac{\cot(\pi
 z)}{(z-a)^2}$$

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow a} (z-a)\frac{\cot(\pi
 z)}{(z-a)^2}$$
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow a} \frac{\cot(\pi
 z)}{(z-a)}=cot(\pi a)$$
Am I correct?. I don't get any series given the option. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form $\cot\pi z=\dfrac{\cos\pi z}{\sin\pi z}$ we know the points $\pi z=kz$ or $z=k\in\mathbb{Z}$ are poles. If $-a\neq k$ then we have a simple pole in $z=k$ so
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Res}_{z=k}\frac{\cot\pi z}{(z+a)^2}
&= \lim_{z\to k} (z-k)\frac{\cot\pi z}{(z+a)^2} \\
&= \lim_{w\to0} w\frac{\cos\pi(w+k)}{(w+k+a)^2\sin\pi(w+k)} \\
&= \lim_{w\to0} w\frac{\cos(k\pi+w\pi)}{(w+k+a)^2\sin(k\pi+w\pi)} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{\pi(k+a)^2}
\end{align}
 If $-a=k$ then we have a pole of order $3$ in $z=k$ so
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Res}_{z=-a}\frac{\cot\pi z}{(z+a)^2}
&= \lim_{z\to-a}\frac{1}{2!}\dfrac{d^2}{dz^2}\left((z+a)^3\frac{\cot\pi z}{(z+a)^2}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2!}\times-2\pi(1+\cot^2\pi(-a)) \\
&= -\pi\csc^2\pi a
\end{align}
then the sum of residues is
$$\color{blue}{\sum_{k=-\infty,k\neq -a}^\infty\dfrac{1}{\pi(k+a)^2}-\pi\csc^2\pi a}$$

Comment: I understood the theory behind second part, but the second derivative gone too complicated. How did you calculate the $Res_{z=-a}$

Comment: $\frac{d^2}{dz^2}(z+a)(cot\pi z)=2(z+a)\pi^2 cosec^2 \pi z cot\pi z$

Comment: I am getting like this. @MyGlasses

Comment: please help me @MyGlasses

Comment: Sorry. I left here. Check you derivative again

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dz}(z+a)cot \pi z =-\pi(z+a) cosec^2\pi z + cot\pi z. right?$$

Comment: @My Glasses: I got it. Thank you. :)

Comment: Second derivative is $2 \pi ^2 (a+x) \cot (\pi  x) \csc ^2(\pi  x)-2 \pi  \csc ^2(\pi  x)$, anyway you're welcome and good luck!

Comment: I got it already, by careful differentiation.

Comment: Anyway thank you again.